# How to set the option selected to true if selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
.filter
   select(name="filter")
     each list in lists
      option(value='?list=' + list, selected=filter == list)= list
```

HTML example

```
<select name="filter">
  <option value='?list=A'> A </option>
  <option value='?list=B' selected> B </option>
</select>
```

`selected = filter ==list`
does not do anything. Not sure where things go wrong. Need to be able to set option selected to true if it is 'A' or 'B'

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selected` attribute is only required to **be present**. It has no value, setting it is redundant and possibly wrong.

> selected
>
> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is initially selected. If the `<option>` element is the descendant of a `<select>` element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single `<option>` of this `<select>` element may have the selected attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

You need to do something like this

```
.filter
    - var lists = ['A','B','C'];
    select(name="filter")
        each list in lists
            if(list=='B')              // < based on condition
                option(selected)= list   // include "selected"
            else
                option()= list           // or not
```